# Capturing the tab click event in Android Tabview

Tags: android, tabs

I have a tabview in my android app with 3 tabs. The tabs are all working fine.

Now I want to perform some additional logic when the tab (on the top) of the currently active tab is clicked.

Here is an example:

In one of my tabs, I provide an option for the user to sort things in different order. When the press the tab of the currently active tab, I want to reset all these sorting.

Is it possible to capture the tab click event in tabview and perform some additional logic?

Edit: Edited for clarity.

Comment: `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`

Comment: TabHost.onTabChangeListener is getting fired only when the tab is changed. But I want the event to be fired, even if the tab header of the currently active tab is clicked.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ares till looking for a solution, I might have found one.
Take a look here: [Android TabWidget detect click on current tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab?tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4):

This is how your code should work :

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(getTabHost().getCurrentTab()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //do whatever you need

        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works. But it is introducing a new problem. Now the tabs are not getting switched when they are clicked. Do I have to call any additional methods to make the tabs change?

Comment: I am working to solve this issue as well... so far I do not have an answer if not to implement you own "switching" code. If you succeed please share :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab

Comment: Vikas shows a fix to make the tabs switch. Inside the listener add: getTabHost().setCurrentTab(getTabHost().getCurrentTab()); Or if the getCurrentTab() gives trouble, create a final int with the tab's index outside the listener, and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

I found one clean and easy solution for Detecting clicks on selected Tab

Steps:

1: Extend TabActivity in your class.
2: In the onResume() method implement the following method

For each tab (i) implement this:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

public void onResume() {

 super.onResume();
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                   count++;
                   tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    //based on your count value..you can do anything...like going back to homepage...
    //    similar thing exist on iphone (double tab a tab..it takes back to homepage)
     }
   });
 }
```

Since we always have a fixed number of tabs, implementing it separately is not a problem.

Comment: Do you mean the onResume() method of the activity? Also it would be helpful, if you can show a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals(v.getTag()))
                {
                    int nextTab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(prevTab);
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(nextTab);
                    prevTab = nextTab;
                }
                else
                    tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag((String) v.getTag());
            } 
        });
    }
```

You need a global variable;

```
    private int prevTab = 1;   //any tab except the initial one.
```

This code works for me. A little ugly thing is you must set same tag for tab and view
For example;

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AnaSayfa.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("firstTab").setIndicator(makeTabIndicator(R.drawable.firstTab, "First Tab" , "firstTab"))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and makeTabIndicator method is like that,

```
    private View makeTabIndicator(int drawable, String text, String viewTag){ 

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
        image.setImageResource(drawable);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(text);

        view.setTag(viewTag);               
        return view;
    }
```