# Android TabWidget detect click on current tab

Tags: android, listener, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am trying to find  way to be able to fire an onclick event on a tab when this tab is the current tab.

I did try this way (among several other) with no success thou.

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> tabId: " + tabId);

    int tabs = getTabWidget().getChildCount();
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "tabs: " + tabs);
    for(int i=0; i<tabs; i++){
        View tab = getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
        if(i==tabHost.getCurrentTab()){
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "tab: " + i);
            tab.setOnClickListener(this);
        }else{
            tab.setOnClickListener(null);
            tab.getOnFocusChangeListener();
        }
    }   
}
```

the point is that I set the `onClickListener` to `null` so, the next time I click on a tab nothing happens, but I would like to have the *normal* tab behavior.

Any idea there outside?

Comment: "I am trying to find way to be able to fire an onclick event on a tab when this tab is the current tab." -- that is not a very discoverable UI pattern. Users do not expect a tap on the current tab to do anything. I encourage you to reconsider your approach.

Comment: I agree with you, my customer dose not :/

Comment: i have a similar situation where each tab has instructions for the user and i want them to be able to click the tab again for the directions to be shown again. i guess it is an unusual pattern but it is the only one i have thought of to make the directions easily reviewable

Comment: After trying most of the solutions in this thread,
I finally solve this problem in just 5 minutes using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2884894/749393) answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, here follows a sample code:

```
    intent = new Intent(this, HomeGroup.class);
    View tab1 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_1,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab1");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(tab1).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    View tab2 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_2,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab2");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(tab2).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    View tab3 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_3,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab3");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(tab3).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    //click on seleccted tab
    int numberOfTabs = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
    for(int t=0; t<numberOfTabs; t++){
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    String currentSelectedTag = MainTab.this.getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag();
                    String currentTag = (String)v.getTag();
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "currentSelectedTag: " + currentSelectedTag + " currentTag: " + currentTag);
                    if(currentSelectedTag.equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)){
                        MainTab.this.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(currentTag);
                        String newSelectedTabTag = MainTab.this.getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag();
                        if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab1")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }else if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab1")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }else if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab3")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Probably it is possible to improve it, but this does the work for me!

Comment: v.getTag() return null for me.

Comment: @ 0m4r ........ can you look into this question ..... http://stackoverflow.com/q/19269322/2825729

Comment: @ 0m4r - Can you please tell me what refers homeTab?

Comment: @Ria homeTab is the view to display when i press a tab button (probably in the snippet above, the fact that I have more then one homeTab is a cut&past error....)

Answer (score 51):

After gothrough many solutions for tab listener, I have found very simple solution...

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
 Log.i("@@@@@@@@ ANN CLICK TAB NUMBER", "------" + i);

    if (i == 0) {
            Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@ Inside onClick tab 0", "onClick tab");

    }
    else if (i ==1) {
            Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@ Inside onClick tab 1", "onClick tab");
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs problem: this only gets called when the tab has changed and not when clicking the same tab.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me to finish one long and crazy project

Comment: @Chirag_CID great answer :-), I have been stuck for last 3 days and this answer solved my exact problem ;)

Comment: @dhaag23 : You should disable current tab to avoid click again. It would be more familiar with users.

Comment: @TranDucHuy - a disabled tab may not be what users want or expect - it all depends on the use case, and as I mentioned, it's not what was asked.

Answer (score 24):

After a lot of thinking about this, the solution ended up being easier than I thought. What I did was just create a new child class that extends TabHost and override the setCurrentTab method like so:

```
package com.mycompany.Views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReclickableTabHost extends TabHost {

    public ReclickableTabHost(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ReclickableTabHost(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentTab(int index) {
        if (index == getCurrentTab()) {
            // FIRE OFF NEW LISTENER
        } else {
            super.setCurrentTab(index);
        }
    }
}
```

To use your new class instead of the typical TabHost just edit your layout xml file with:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight=".8">

    <com.myCompany.Views.ReclickableTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.myCompany.Views.ReclickableTabHost>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Seems like the most reliable solution. Thanks Steve.

Comment: Great answer. I added `public interface OnReClickListener { public void onReClick(int index); }` an and ivar `private OnReClickListener onReClickListener;` (plus getters and setters) as well as this code to fire off the listener: `if (null != onReClickListener) { onReClickListener.onReClick(index);}` Hope that helps.

Comment: It is also important to add check isShown() before notifying listener. Because android calls setCurrentTab if user locks/unlocks device.

Answer (score 15):

Ugly fix:IN the onClickListener put :
`tabHost.SetCurrentTab(OtherTab);
tabHost.SetCurrentTab(CurrentTab);`
Where for index of Other Tab I use my simplest view under the tabs.

P.S. Customers always want their apps to be different :)

This is the code that I use (I have only 2 tabs Tab1 and Tab2):

```
 getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                Log.d(TAG,"1"+getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag());

                if (getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("Tab2")) { 
                    Log.d(TAG,"2");

                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);                                    
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

                } else {
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                }
            } 
        });
```

Comment: what do you mean with " Where for index of Other Tab I use my simplest view under the tabs."?

Comment: I have been trying your solution but I still have the problem that *overrriding* the default onClick event on the tab I *override* the default behavior... and setting it to null remove the onClick event at all.... so, thanks for your help but I think I can't use your solution unless I rewrite the whole onClick event for the tab :/

Comment: useful with two tabs, with more than two I would not know how to manage it :) But thanks anyhow!

Comment: override the onTouchListener instead and return false inside onTouch, Using onClick will cause the tabs to stop changing

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that `setOnTabChangedListener` does not fire when clicking on the selected tab, and if you set an `OnClickListener` on the tab, you lose the normal tab behavior.

So an easy solution is to put `OnClickListener` on the tab, and inside it, set programatically that this is the current tab.

With `TabHost`:

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // custom code
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);                                    
    }
});
```

With `TabLayout`

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0)setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    // custom code
                    TabLayout.Tab tab  = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
                    tab.select();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to try **android.support.design.widget.TabLayout**, you can achieve it like this:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
   @Override public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {

   }

   @Override public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab) {

   }

   @Override public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {

   }
});
```

Comment: Hey @AmiAram, thanks for [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15464249). Unfortunately, it didn't go through. But it is good suggestion  and I changed my answer with that!

Answer (score 1):

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            int i = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#014a68"));

            //int m = mTabHost.getChildCount();
            for (int j = 0; j <=3; j++) {
                if (j != i)
                    mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                            .getChildAt(j)
                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me...

```
TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

host.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        int i = host.getCurrentTab();

        if (i == 0) {
             // your method 1
        }
        else if (i ==1) {
            // your method 2
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom tab layout, you might need to add this in your custom view, it solved my problem:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```