# android crash exception with no root point

Tags: android, exception, android-viewpager

What can I do when I get an Exception but can't understand where to looking for

I mean I know it's in my NewHomeTabActivity, but where should I start searching. I try to insert some logs line and break point but still can't resolve the root cause

```
01-07 13:39:33.133: W/dalvikvm(12350): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c471f8) 
01-07 13:39:33.133: W/System.err(12350): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onTabClicked(View) in the activity class att.uc.ui.screen.NewHomeTabActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout with id 'tab_dialer' 
01-07 13:39:33.138: W/System.err(12350): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3085) 
01-07 13:39:33.143: W/System.err(12350): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620) 
01-07 13:39:33.143: W/System.err(12350): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292) 
01-07 13:39:33.143: W/System.err(12350): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
01-07 13:39:33.148: W/System.err(12350): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
01-07 13:39:33.148: W/System.err(12350): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-07 13:39:33.148: W/System.err(12350): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507) 
01-07 13:39:33.153: W/System.err(12350): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-07 13:39:33.153: W/System.err(12350): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-07 13:39:33.153: W/System.err(12350): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980) 
01-07 13:39:33.158: W/System.err(12350): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747) 
01-07 13:39:33.158: W/System.err(12350): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-07 13:39:33.158: W/System.err(12350): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onTabClicked [class android.view.View] 
01-07 13:39:33.163: W/System.err(12350): at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460) 
01-07 13:39:33.163: W/System.err(12350): at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915) 
01-07 13:39:33.168: W/System.err(12350): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3078) 
01-07 13:39:33.173: W/System.err(12350): ... 11 more
```

Comment: Put your relevant code Here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the stactrace from bottom to up line by line to get the relevant message.
It crashes because it cannot find the method `onTabClicked(View)` in your activity.

I'm assuming that you have an XML control which is given the `onClick` property, something like this:

```
android:onClick="onTabClicked"
```

If so, then your activity should have a method called `onTabClicked(View view)` that accepts a parameter of type `View`, this is mandatory.
Like this:

```
public void onTabClicked(View view){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log suggest it is a RunTimeException so you cannot find it by putting logs ,
the onTabClicked method you have used (maybe defined in xml file ) is not found at RunTime ,
this could be because you have called a higher sdk version while building against lower sdk version , you can either target higher sdk version or use alternative approach for onclick

similar link can suggest a possible solution [Android TabWidget detect click on current tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab?tab=active#tab-top)