# Android: Start the camera by clicking the scan tab

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-tabhost

I have a scan tab which is already selected . When it is pressed for first time it starts the camera. and if we press back without scanning the below image is seen. now i want to again start the camera by clicking the scan tab, without changing the tab.how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Post some relevant code so that one can provide you solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning to your activity perform setSelected(false) on your tab.

Comment: True my bad. Please refer to this post it will surely help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab/7750320#7750320